# cannot convert node to node_t* in assignment

Tags: c

I've tried everything, line 59 has this error from title.

There is .dat file I have to sort from .dat and print in .exe.

When compiling it says it cannot convert. what could it be?

I've only included the problematic function and the main code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int value;
    struct node * next;
} node_t;

struct node push(node_t * head, int val)
{
    node_t * current = head;
    while (current->next != NULL) 
    {
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    current->next->value = val;
    current->next->next = NULL;
    return current;
}

int main() {
    node_t * list = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    FILE* file = fopen ("kol1.dat", "r");
    int i = 0;   
    do
    {
        fscanf (file, "%d", &i);
        list = push(list, i);
        list = sort_list(list); 
        print_list(list);    
    }while (!feof (file));
    fclose (file);  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: there is no line 59 here.

Comment: C is not C++ is not C! Pick one language.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Note my comment.

Comment: @Olaf agreed. However, just thought, `#include <stdio.h>` is more `c`-ish. :-)

Comment: yeah sorry, I've shortened it that's why there's no line 59. Problem is the return value from push function. It's c++, they're similar :(

Comment: So `list` is a pointer. `push` returning a struct. Decide on on which side you are.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm on the pointing side, however I have no clue how to return it trough push function.

Comment: Java and C# also have a "similar" syntax. Just use the tag for the language you compile.

Comment: But you should not program like that in C++. Make it C and remove the discouraged casts.

Comment: @Olaf thanks for the tip, will do so in future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `current` is `struct node*` but your `push` function is returning a `struct node`.

So changing

```
struct node push(node_t * head, int val)
```

to

```
struct node *push(node_t * head, int val)
```

should do the job.

Comment: compiled&run and it works, thanks a lot !